# Conditional if statement after AJAX post using response, is this ok?

Tags: php, ajax, if-statement

A form i'm using with a single input uses AJAX to post to the server. I plan to take the input's value which is a string and check if the string already exists in the database. I'll us `in_array()` and if the string doesn't exist insert it to the database and echo 1 or else 0 if it's a duplicate, sending back 1 or 0 as a result.

In my AJAX i'm using this simple function on success, if the result returns 1 i'll use jQuery to display a success message, or else i'll display an error and exit. Is this a good method to validate server side and not have the form submit by returning 1 or 0 and `exit();` for duplicates?

```
    success: function(result)
    {
      if(result == 1)
    { string was inserted to db }
    else
    { 
duplicate exists 
      exit();
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: @DrixsonOseña if I don't use exit(); the form continues to submit the AJAX request, even if 0 is returned.

Comment: you can use `event.preventDefault();`  for not your form to submit and let ajax run only. Is this what you need?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña no I already have that in my javascript.

Comment: so you mean there is wrong in your ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have personally made it so in the php, I return a json encoded identity array with some of the information about the response. I usually include more information than needed, for debugging purposes and possible future changes.

```
if($results >= 1){
    $duplicate_exists = 'true';
}elseif($results < 1){
    $duplicate_exists = 'false';
};

$result = array(
    'exists' => $duplicate_exists ,
    'status' => $status,
    'time' => time()
    // etc
);

echo  json_encode($result)
```

Then to decode the json into an object in javascript:

```
success: function(result){
    result = jQuery.parseJSON(result)
// you can also use eval(result) , but it's much slower.
    if(result.exists == 'false'){
        // string was inserted to db
    }else{ 
        // duplicate exists 
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Jack in my .ajax() I habe data: serializedData. So on the server I can encode my results to json. Then within the success function I can parse the json response?

Comment: Yes. If you do `console.log(result)` inside your success, then check your javascript console, it should be a json string. If you take that string and `eval()` or `jQuery.parseJSON()` it, it will turn it into an Object.

Comment: Great thanks, I was looking on jQuery's docs about the success settings and the data formts it returns but wasn't sure how to use them.

Comment: Instead of doing `}else{` in the javascript, I think it would be better to do `}else if(result.exists == 'true'){`. Since you are going to tell the user that there's a duplicate, you should specify in the coding that it's a duplicate, because when something else that isn't those 2 things happens, it shouldn't fall back on the duplicate error.

Comment: I just outputted the results to my console and see the status null and time stamp. So in result.exists, exists is a key and true / false is the value it's checking for, similarly I could then use results.status, and results.time or any other key/value in an array created server side?

Comment: The reason status is null is because `$status` isn't defined in your php file. `results.exist` is a string. Instead of "true" and "false", you could use "apple" and "pear" and it would run exactly the same. Whatever you put into that array in the php file, will become part of the object `result`. You can name anything in it you want. You can put strings that are thousands of characters long if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code using `AJAX` and `JS` to post and retrieve the result.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/gists',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',

        data: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .success( function(e) {

       res = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
       if(res.exists == 'false'){
        // string was inserted to db
       }
       else if(res.exists == 'true'){ 
        // duplicate exists 
        exit();
      }


      })
      .error( function(e) {

        //there was error

      });
```